# Using Joda DateTime on the backend, how do I convert to a JavaScript Date object?

Tags: java, javascript, jodatime

I'm using the [Joda DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) object (per SO recommendations) heavily on the Java back-end of my application.  But I've not figured out a very consistent way to go back and forth to JavaScript.  The [Date object described by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) seems to indicate that *["IETF-compliant RFC 1123 timestamps"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123)* are a standard format, but my searches didn't seem to turn up a formatter built into the Joda library to get my [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object in that format.

Is there a simple method I can invoke to convert a DateTime object to a format consumable by my web-client?  Will it support IE8 (in terms of JavaScript)?

****Note**: I'm not using Spring or anything that does automatic binding (serialization/deserialization) and it's not an option at this point.  I know, I know...*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the *miliseconds since epoch* version of the javascript `Date` constructor. For the conversion you can use [`DateTimeUtils.getInstantMillis(ReadableInstant instant)`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#getInstantMillis%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29).

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Ed I disagree with you. The poster asked "Is there a simple method I can invoke to convert a DateTime object to a format consumable by my web-client?" And one answer to that is to convert the `DateTime` to the *number of seconds since epoch* it represents and transfer this to the browser, where you can easily create a `Date` object out of it and display it. (If needed, with `Date.toLocaleString()`.)

Comment: You're right - I was hung up on Brian thinking he needed a formatter.

Comment: @Ed Staub -  Thank you guys so much!  A very concise and simple answer, swapped out the code I had for this and I was up and running in minutes!  Ed, sorry for the confusion about a _"formatter"_, I should have used other language to describe what I was after.  Thank you both very much!